# WPF scrollview scrolled to the bottom default

Tags: wpf, listbox, scrollviewer

I have a `ScrollViewer` containing a `ListBox`. I would like the `ScrollViewer` to scroll all the way to the bottom by default when the view has been loaded! This because the most recent element is always the last element in the `ListBox`.

Is there an easy way to achieve this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have access to the `ScrollViewer`, you could also use the [`ScrollViewer.ScrollToBottom()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltobottom.aspx) method.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a easy way.

```
lv.ScrollIntoView(lv.Items[0]);
```

This will scroll to the first item. All you need to do is to find your last item.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if the ScrollToBottom method doesnt go all the way to the bottom (stops 1 item short), call the `ScrollViewer.UpdateLayout()` method just before your call to `ScrollViewer.ScrollToBottom`.

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy and works:

```
myListBox.ScrollIntoView(lastObjectAdded);
```

I know this isn't the most elegant solution but at least for string object works very well.

Comment: the other solutions are much better.